# Is there a more efficient way to do this Linq to EF query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

Is there a more efficient way to do this query?

```
var subscriptions = from user in Db.User
                    from city in Db.City
                    where user.City.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(city.Id)
                       && user.Id == User.Id
                    select city.Id;
```

Generated statement

```
SELECT 
[Extent2].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM  [dbo].[User] AS [Extent1]
CROSS JOIN [dbo].[City] AS [Extent2]
WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[UserCity] AS [Extent3]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent3].[UserId]) AND ([Extent3].[CityId] = [Extent2].[Id])
)) AND ([Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nick explained its a many-to-many relationship so modifying answer based on that assuming this is designed properly.

You will need an inbetween table to manage this properly. I will make up a table that is not listed as it must contain this table in order for this design to make sense.

Let's say there is a table:

```
table CitiesAndUsers
    column cityId int
    column userId int
```

assuming cityID and userID are composite keys and foreign keys  to their respective tables

Now for the lamda

```
var subscriptions = Db.CitiesAndUsers.Where(cu => cu.User.Id == User.Id).Select(cu => cu.City.id);
```

Makes sense?

Comment: It is a many-to-many relationship between `User` and `City`. This won't work because `u => u.City` is a collection of `City`

Comment: If that is not right then you should go back to your question and write more detail of your tables. That way can get better answers. Cheers.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks. However, my model doesn't have the join table. Just a *----* line representing the many-to-many relationship. Any ideas?

Comment: You should write a foreign key in your SQL for both keys, delete the table in your GUI designery thing, then refresh DB and drag it back in. You need to have both of those keys be a composite primary key + making them refer to the table sources. This is just good practice in relational databases.

Comment: That's exactly what I did when designing my database. The model designer abstracted the join tables away. That is why I am curious about other ways to join using EF.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can create a relation between your tow table to do that easier like this :

```
Db.User.City.Select(x => x.Id)
```

but if you are forced to do that with out any relation , i just say that you do that right with your solution